# Initial black screen, long boot up, no bios info, no Win logo, directly into the desktop screen

Tags: boot, display, bios

There are similar threads on the net but my problem is different.

My computer has recently started to start with a black screen, no BIOS info is displayed, no windows logo is displayed. 3-10 minutes later, monitor suddenly an directly displays the desktop screen.

I changed the battery. Thus clean CMOS. No success.

I removed the additional graphics card and reverted to the onboard graphics.

I Made driver and BIOS modifications. No success.

I made a BIOS flash.

Then I made a clean Windows install. No success.

I ran MemTest86+. No errors.

I reseated all components. No success.

There is one more unusual thing. When the computer is finally up and running with no problems, I can restart the computer without the problems I mentioned above. Such a normal boot up takes only 20-25 seconds. In other words, when the components are warm there is no problem of normal restarting. That’s how I make BIOS modifications.

But when I shut down the computer and start an hour later, I face the same  problem again.

I would appreciate comments and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the battery doesn't inherently clear the CMOS, unless the power cable had been removed and time had been alloted for discharge between removing and replacing (not specified in question).

Do you have a different monitor you could test with?  All of the symptoms you described could be had with a faulty monitor which takes time to 'warm up' before displaying.

Please test with another display.  If the results are the same, if you have not yet done so, clear the CMOS with the above method.  I believe the first will resolve the issue.